# Set DATE parameter default to dynamically calculated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with two DATE parameters that I want to have a default value.  However, I also want to be able to override these values as needed.  I'm using SSMS 18. Here's how I would like my code to work. (this is not a working example)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_stuff_and_things
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @begin_date DATE = (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) )
     ,@end_date DATE = (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) )
    
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
```

These two parameters are grabbing the first day of the previous month (@begin_date) and the last day of the previous month (@end_date). These default values work most of the time, but I'm sometimes required to pull a custom date range.  I'd like to be able to pass values like this to the stored proc as needed.

```
EXEC dbo.usp_stuff_and_things @begin_date = '2021-01-01', @end_date = '2021-12-31'
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DEFAULT` value for a procedure *must* be a literal, it can't be an expression, and certainly can't be resolved from a `SELECT` statement. Instead you could `DEFAULT` the value to `NULL` and then assign their value to an expression within the procedure's definition if the value is `NULL`:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_stuff_and_things
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @begin_date DATE = NULL,
     @end_date DATE = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @begin_date IS NULL
        SET @begin_date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0);

    IF @end_date IS NULL
        SET @end_date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1);

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

END;
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use an expression for the default. Try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_stuff_and_things
    @begin_date date = NULL,
    @end_date   date = NULL   
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  
  SET @end_date   = COALESCE(@end_date, 
        EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2));

  SET @begin_date = COALESCE(@begin_date,
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, @end_date));
END
GO
```

`EOMONTH()` doesn't have a lot of value in most cases IMHO, but it is an easy way to determine month boundaries dynamically. Some other methods that are better than the messy and cryptic dateadd/datediff approaches:

- [Simplify Date Period Calculations in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6088/simplify-date-period-calculations-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

I'd also really recommend avoiding `yyyy-mm-dd` format, as it can be misinterpreted in some contexts as `yyyy-dd-mm`:

- [What date/time literal formats are LANGUAGE and DATEFORMAT safe?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166771/1186)

Though I have to say, a begin date the day after the end date doesn't make a lot of sense.